# htaccess rewrite redirect from parameters to the subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want that when you go to url: https://www.example.com/subdir/?id=1

redirects to

https://www.example.com/subdir/

How can I do that in my .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the permalink setting on the admin panel **POST NAME**, it will work.